# No X509TrustManager implementation available [SOAP Node IIB 10 ]

Tags: soap-client, ibm-integration-bus

I'm trying to use soap request node with an ssl ws , in my case i downloaded the certif .cer in the folder (E:\truststore) and i tried to do the some think :

```
mqsireportproperties integrationNodeName -o ComIbmJVMManager -a -e integration_server

mqsichangeproperties integrationNodeName -e integration_server -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststoreFile -v E:\truststore

mqsichangeproperties integrationNodeName -e integration_server -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststorePass -v integration_server::truststorePass

mqsisetdbparms IIBOAB -n integration_server::truststorePass -u na -p password
```

but i have this error :

> Text:CHARACTER:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager
>   implementation available

can you please help me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can have multiple reasons, so I will try to recap everything here :

Your command to set the keystore doesn't specify the keystore/truststore names.  Also, in my memories, you are suppose to set it on BrokerRegistry, not on ComIbmJVMManager (but it might work) 
An example of valid commands :

```
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -o BrokerRegistry -n brokerKeystoreFile -v $KEYSTORE_iib_PATH/iib.jks
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -o BrokerRegistry -n brokerTruststoreFile -v $KEYSTORE_iibTrust_PATH/iibTrust.jks
mqsisetdbparms $BROKERNAME -n brokerTruststore::password -u $KEYSTORE_USER -p $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
mqsisetdbparms $BROKERNAME -n brokerKeystore::password -u $KEYSTORE_USER-p $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
```

In addition, you might also need the following commands for the http listener :

```
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -b httplistener -o HTTPListener -n enableSSLConnector -v true
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -b httplistener -o HTTPSConnector -n keystoreFile -v $KEYSTORE_iib_PATH/iib.jks
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -b httplistener -o HTTPSConnector -n truststoreFile -v $KEYSTORE_iibTrust_PATH/iibTrust.jks
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -b httplistener -o HTTPSConnector -n keystorePass -v $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -b httplistener -o HTTPListener  -n startListener -v true
```

This is it for the Integration Bus part. Your second mistake (and probably the biggest one) is the fact you don't know what is a keystore/trustore. Putting certificate in a repository IS NOT a keystore. (Search a bit about JKS : Java Key Store)

You could do the following to generate your truststore/keystore on Unix :

```
keystoreName=iibTrust.jks
KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=123qwerty ## DO NOT USE THAT PLEASE
for certificate in `ls *.cer`;
do
    alias=`echo $certificate | rev | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev | cut -d '_' -f2`
    keytool -importcert -file $certificate -keystore ${keystoreName}.jks -alias $alias -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -noprompt
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then "Unable to add $certificate in keystore $keystoreName.jks";
done    
keytool -list -keystore ${keystoreName}.jks -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
```

I've basically copy / pasted all my scripts to enables SSL on IIB, so with all these info you should be able to make it work.